# python for-loop only executes once?

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, for-loop

```
import numpy as np
def Vin(t):
    inputs = []
    for i in range (1000):
        if (-1)**(np.floor( 2 * t[i] )) == 1:
            Vin = (1)
            inputs.append(Vin)
        else:
            Vin = (-1)
            inputs.append(Vin)

        return inputs
```

when I use this function on a range of `t` values, I only get one result,

i.e.

```
input1=Vin(tpoints)
print (input1)
```

only gives [1], whereas I want the function to do it for every `t` value.

Comment: As soon as your function hits a `return`, the function is finished. If you want to run the whole loop before you return, put the `return` statement after the loop instead of inside it.

Comment: You are exiting at the first iteration of  loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning from with in the for loop,So you would return from the function on first iteration of the loop.

you may re-writ e the function as following

**Code**

```
def Vin(t):
    inputs = []
    for i in range (1000):
        if (-1)**(np.floor( 2 * t[i] )) == 1:
            inputs.append(1)
        else:
            inputs.append(-1)
    return inputs
```

Check the indentation of *return inputs* in the function here .

BTW, your function can be reduced to as more pythonic and efficient code

```
def Vin(t):
 reduce map(lambda x:int((-1)**(np.floor( t[i] < 1))), range (1000))
```

Answer (score 3):

As others said, there's an indentation error in your `return` statement. I couldn't resist rewriting your code in a more pythonic way, avoiding all that cumbersome loops and the resulting errors:

```
return [1 if (-1)**(np.floor( 2 * t[i] )) == 1 else -1 for i in range (1000)]
```

that list comprenhension + ternary construction statement creates your -1,1 array in 1 line, much faster than you'd write with a loop.

Comment: The function can be reduced even further ,check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 for i in range (1000):
        if (-1)**(np.floor( 2 * t[i] )) == 1:
            Vin = (1)
            inputs.append(Vin)
        else:
            Vin = (-1)
            inputs.append(Vin)

 return inputs
```

Current indentation of return , exits the for loop after 1st iteration