# How to select sub-strings based on the presence of word pairs? Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large number of sentences, from which I want to extract sub-sentences that start with certain word combinations. For example, I want to extract sentence segments that begin with "what does" or "what is', etc. (essentially eliminating the words from the sentence that appear before the word-pairs). Both the sentences and the word-pairs are stored in a `DataFrame`:

```
'Sentence'                                    'First2'                                    
0  If this is a string what does it say?      0 can I    
1  And this is a string, should it say more?  1 should it    
2  This is yet another string.                2 what does
3  etc. etc.                                  3 etc. etc
```

The result I want from the above example would be:

```
0 what does it say?
1 should it say more?
2
```

The most obvious solution (at least to me) below does not work. It only uses the first word-pair `b` to go over all the sentences `r`, but not the other `b`'s.

```
a = df['Sentence']
b = df['First2'] 

#The function seems to loop over all r's but only over the first b:
def func(z): 
    for x in b:
        if x in r:
            s = z[z.index(x):] 
            return s
        else:
            return ‘’

df['Segments'] = a.apply(func)
```

It seems that looping over two DataFrames simultaneously in this way does not work. Is there a more efficient and effective way to do this?

Comment: Accumulate `s` in a container and don't `return` till the loop completes.  There is a duplicate Q&A for this somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python for-loop only executes once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933378/python-for-loop-only-executes-once)

Comment: Adding a container and not doing `return` until the loop completes works. But the results look strange: `[, , , , , , , , what does that say?,...` It seems the deleted words are replaced by (empty) elements in a list, while the selected text as a whole becomes an element in the list.

Comment: One question at a time. Refactor and repost if there is a problem you can't solve in the *new* code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a bug in your code.

```
else:
    return ''
```

This means if the 1st comparison is not a match, 'func' will return immediately. That might be why the code does not return any matches.

A sample working code is below:

```
# The function seems to loop over all r's but only over the first b:
def func(sentence, first_twos=b):
    for first_two in first_twos:
        if first_two in sentence:
            s = sentence[sentence.index(first_two):]
            return s
    return ''

df['Segments'] = a.apply(func)
```

And the output:

```
df:   
{   
'First2': ['can I', 'should it', 'what does'],   
'Segments': ['what does it say? ', 'should it say more?', ''],   
'Sentence': ['If this is a string what does it say? ', 'And this is a string, should it say more?', 'This is yet another string.  '  ]  
}
```

Comment: You are right about the bug in my code! When I replace it by the last two lines of your answer (`return s` and `return ''`) I get the desired result. However, `.apply` works in my Python code. I only replace the two return lines, nothing else, and now it works. Your suggested last line does not work in my code. If you could replace it by: `df['Segments'] = a.apply(func)` then I can accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @twhale: modified. Thanks :). Also the `apply` comes from `pandas.DataFrame.apply`.

Answer (score 1):

you can loop over two things easily via `zip(iterator,iterator_foo)`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: How this be integrated in my code above? Especially to get `s = z[z.index(x):]`

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered by the following code:

```
def func(r):
    for i in b:
        if i in r:
            q = r[r.index(i):]
            return q
    return ''

df['Segments'] = a.apply(func)
```

The solution was pointed out here by [Daming Lu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4465846/daming-lu) (only the last line is different from his). The problem was in the last two lines of the original code:

```
else:
    return ''
```

This caused the function to return too early. Daming Lu's answer was better than the answer to the possible duplicate question [python for-loop only executes once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933378/python-for-loop-only-executes-once) which created other problems - as explained in my respons to wii. (So I am not sure mine really is a duplicate.)